# Calculate billable days in date range based on predefined week length

Tags: excel

I am attempting to devise a formula that will allow for the correct billing days based on a predefined week length. Take this example:

- Qty: 5
- Price Per: $1
- Date Start: 1/1/2017
- Date End: 1/7/2017
- Days Per Week: 3
- **Total billed:** $15

Billing on a 3 day week would mean that 1-3 days would be billed on `(Qty * Price Per)` but days 4-7 are essentially free. This would have to work for long period also.

More Examples:

- Qty: 5
- Price Per: $1
- Date Start: 1/1/2017
- Date End: 1/8/2017
- Days Per Week: 1
- **Total billed:** $10

> 

- Qty: 5
- Price Per: $1
- Date Start: 1/1/2017
- Date End: 1/10/2017
- Days Per Week: 1
- **Total billed:** $10
  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is between the start date and the end date always 7 days?

Comment: No, this is variable. It can be any duration. - It should also be noted that the "Days per week" can be anything 1 - 3. Where 1 day week works out to basically week count.

Comment: so if the Date End was: 1/14/2017 you would expect the total billed to be $30?

Comment: Correct! and if it was 1/15/17 it would be $35

Comment: Is day `1` always `Date Start` or is it a specific day of the week?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=MIN(MOD(B4-B3+1,7),B5)*B1*B2+INT((B4-B3+1)/7)*B1*B2*B5
```

where:

> B1: Qty
>
> B2: Price Per
>
> B3: Date Start
>
> B4: Date End
>
> B5: Days per Week

With this setup:

[image]

Breaking it down:

- lesser of number days left over after subtracting the whole weeks, or maximum number of days to count in a week   `MIN(MOD(B4-B3+1,7),B5)`

  - multiply by `Qty * Price Per`
- number of whole weeks  `INT((B4-B3+1)/7)`

  - multiply by `Qty * Price Per * Days in Week`

Comment: Nice answer, much simpler!